# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu' (113)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I realize this question exists, but going through the replies I could not find a solution to my problem. I am trying to connect to a remoter server:

```
mysqladmin -u root -h 'genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu' --port=3306 version -p
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu' failed
error: 'Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113'
```

I have checked that mysql is running:

```
arron@arron-Ideapad-Z570 ~ mysqladmin -u root -h 'localhost' --port=3306 version -p
Enter password: 
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.1.69, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.1.69-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         13 days 21 hours 45 min 33 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 154  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 255  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 62  Queries per second avg: 0.0
```

Also this doesn't work either

```
mysql --user=genome --host=genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu -A -N -D uniProt
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu' (113)
```

and I have removed

```
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

from my msql.cnf file.

The problem however still persists. does anyone have any suggestions?

I am using Linux Mint 12 and network is a university campus. if there is a firewall issue, how do I check this on my system?

Comment: Are you sure that you have root access to the remote server? This is in a typical installation constrained to local users. Can you connect using mysql instead of mysqladmin? Or as another user which is not root?

Comment: Hi Alex have tried both - updated question to reflect this.

Comment: The big question: Is the user you're using to connect to the server remotely with access to your database from that IP or does the user in question have a wildcard access?